# BizTalk - Why does a suspended message appear in the console for a handled exception?

Tags: exception, biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

Here is an image of a common structure we have in a few of our BizTalk orchestrations: [image]

So when we GET information from an API and the account doesn't exist, we terminate the orchestration. This works fine and I can see the orchestration doing this and terminating when it should, but what I don't understand is why do I see the suspended message from the GET in the console? Since the exception handling works, shouldn't this stop an error showing in the console?

As a way around this, I've considered using a pipeline component to check the response message, and if it contains what would be ignored, just return null in place of the message. Would this have the desired effect? I'm more interested as to why I see the suspended messages in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a known issue  with the WCF-WebHttp adapter, that has to do with the fact that it throws it back as a SOAP formatted error, but without setting the MessageType context property (see my [blog post](https://cdijkgraaf.wordpress.com/2016/08/12/biztalk-2013-r2-known-bugs-issues-quirks/) and look for Bug: BizTalk WCF-WebHttp adapter does not set the message type on error).  So although the exception is thrown back at the Orchestration and can be handled there, the message is not as BizTalk does not know what type it is and it suspends.

A workaround we use is

1. To set Enable Routing for failed messages on the send port
2. To have a send port that subscribes to all the response messages from that send port using the `BTS.SPName = xxxx` filter, and send port sends it to a custom NULL adapter (throw the message away), and yes, your Orchestration will still get the good response as well as the exceptions.
3. Update the send port that handles routing errors from other send ports that we do want to go to our exception handing to exclude those send ports which we are handling via an Orchestration.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Does this bug still persist in newer versions of BizTalk?

Comment: @jevi Not certain as I haven't tested it yet, but I've seen no "fix" being announced for it, so I would think, yes.